# How can I show line numbers in Code tab of Talend?

Tags: talend

Whenever I click on the Code tab to see the Java code of Talend job, I never see see the line numbers. Is there any settings to enable line numbers?

Comment: you can directly right click in code tab and select Show line number

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can enable line numbers from **Preferences**

You will see a parameter for `Show line numbers` if you follow this breadcrumb -

> Window > Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors

Comment: I had to restart talend, then only change reflected, but it worked. Thanks.